# How to see currently connected clients of vsftp

Tags: vsftpd

I'm using vsftpd. Now I would like to now if - and if, who - someone is currently connected to the server.

Is it possible to find out, if anybody is connected, how many and even who is connected?

Comment: Did you took a look at /var/log/vsftp.log file?

Answer (score 2):

You should set `setproctitle_enable` to `YES` in your `vsftpd.conf`. From [man 5 vsftpd.conf](http://linux.die.net/man/5/vsftpd.conf):

> **setproctitle_enable**
>   If enabled, vsftpd will try and show session status information in the system process listing. In other words, the reported name of the process will change to reflect what a vsftpd session is doing (idle, downloading etc). You probably want to leave this off for security purposes.

Now you can do a `ps axuw | grep vsftp` (or whatever you like) and see connected users.