# Process Monitoring live log

Tags: process, ftp, vsftpd

I would like to monitor a process (vsftpd) under ubuntu 21.10 and I would like to do on command line. It's possible to see when someone is connected and when the download is running? I tried vsftpdwho but it's not live monitoring..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to see currently connected clients of vsftp](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150992/how-to-see-currently-connected-clients-of-vsftp)

Comment: I have that option enable on vsftpd.conf but I would like to scroll log if someone download something and see the user activites...